# Better than expected bias corrected estimator for scale parameter of Logistic random deviates based on sample standard deviation?

Tags: distributions, logistic, simulation, point-estimation

Background:

Using the quantile function (inverse cumulative distribution) for the Logistic distribution supplied with uniform random deviates (per the RAND() spreadsheet function), I was testing various estimators for the mean and scale parameter of the Logistic distribution in a spreadsheet setting.

I worked with a sample of 50 and computed the average, variance, and fitted a regression model (based on Least-Squares (L-S) and Least-Absolute deviations (LAD) to random logits computed from a rank sorting of the data. Both L-S and LAD perform well especially on the scale parameter as compared to the true underlying mean selected value.

I wanted to compare their performance to more simple sample estimates, so using the citing relationship between the sample variance and scale parameter for the Logistic distribution (see, [for example, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution)), I quickly derived an estimator, as to quote:

> Variance: ${s^2/{{\Pi}^2}/3}$

One can easily derive an undoubtedly bias estimator upon solving for *s*. However, upon examining results **without** a bias correction factor, it became apparent that applying such a factor might make the sample variance-based scale parameter more competitive in terms of its accuracy to the known simulation value (I used an absolute error criteria).

To my surprise, on enumerating some 60 sample results and taking the indicated median (which at this point, was close to the observed mean value for the correction factor), I derived a quick suggested bias correction factor of 1.31, for a sample of 50 simulated Logistic random deviates.

Then, on further comparison runs, it appeared that this bias-corrected factor (employing its cited relationship to on the variance of Logistic random deviates) was clearly outperforming both the LAD (robust) and the graphical L-S model in determining the scale factor.

A search of the web produces little on this topic other than yes, the scale parameter of the Logistic distribution is proportional to the standard deviation. My point, is it possible that the variance-based estimator, with even a rapidly assessed bias correction factor, actually performs much better than some (including myself) expected? One may, however, have to derive, at least, an approximate scale correction factor via testing as I did for varying sample sizes and such.

Comment: I thought I should mention that I have just similarly looked at the case of the Laplace distribution where the MLE estimate b (scale parameters the sample estimate) as derived from the mean absolute deviation. Again, even a crude estimate derived from the variance is at least (or seemingly better) than based on a sample of 100 Laplace random deviates for each simulation and a bias correction  factor independently based 105 trials of indicated bias to the true value which I rounded to 1.02 (close to the average of the median and average indicated correction factor) than b.

Comment: Here is a link to a now posted question based on the Laplace distribution which also cites related comments in the literature at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465640/surprising-nonlinear-variance-based-scale-est-bias-adj-for-laplace-distributio .